# Flitering django queryset based on ManyToManyField

Tags: python, django, many-to-many, django-queryset

In my `Request` model, there is a field `requested_to` which is a `ManyToManyField`

```py
requested_to = models.ManyToManyField(OrganizationUser)
```

I want to filter queryset of `Request` model where a `organization_user` is not in `requested_to`

Comment: You could do: `Request.objects.filter(~Q(requested_to=organization_user))`

Comment: Thanks @BrianDestura it works but how the equality check implies here as ```requesgted_to``` is a collection of ```OrganizationUser``` and ```organization_user``` is a single instance of ```OrganizationUser```

Comment: You can find the explanation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) (search for "lookups across relationships"). It then links to [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships) where it is explained that this format is used by django to do the SQL JOINs for you automatically. The example if interest is the one with `Blog.objects.filter(entry__headline__contains='Lennon')`, where a blog can have multiple entries.

Comment: Ah you might want @Willem Van Onsem's answer as it is terser, but both our answers will end up with the same SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter with:

```
Request.objects.exclude(requested_to=organization_user)
```

Django makes LEFT OUTER JOINs when you filter on a `ManyToManyField` (or a reverse `ForeignKey`), so here we exclude all `Request`s where `organization_user` is a member of the `requested_to`.